# jQuery function load or resize inconsistent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function which check whether a DOM element overflows the y-axis of the viewport, and applied a class to a different DOM element if that is the case. I want it to work on load and on resize:

```
    $.fn.overflowsViewport = function() {
        var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
        var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
        var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
        return elementBottom > viewportBottom;
    };

    $(window).on('load resize', function() {
        if ($('#list .list').overflowsViewport()) {
            $("#post").addClass("shorter");
        } else {
            $("#post").removeClass("shorter");
        }
    });
```

This works on load, but only some of the time. Resize is fine.

I presume that something is causing the function to run before the page has fully loaded on some occasions. Usually a hard refresh will create the desired effect, but we can't expect the user to know/do that.

How can I make sure this function is loaded correctly so as to produce a consistent result? Or is timing not the issue here?

Comment: There are multiple solutions to this issue, but the simplest way to retrofit into your existing code is to wrap it inside a `$(document).ready(function(){ /* your code here */ });`.

Comment: Where is `elementTop` and `viewportTop` defined? I do not see them defined in the scope of the Function. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Twisty yes you're right – these somehow weren't copied over but they were there in my files. I've updated the question, although you've answered it already, for the sake of accuracy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $.fn.overflowsViewport = function() {
    var elementBottom = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
    var viewportBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    console.log(elementBottom, viewportBottom);
    return elementBottom > viewportBottom;
  };

  function checkOverflow() {
    if ($('#list .list').overflowsViewport()) {
      $("#post").addClass("shorter");
    } else {
      $("#post").removeClass("shorter");
    }
  }

  $(window).resize(checkOverflow);
  checkOverflow();
});
```

```css
.list {
  height: 450px;
}

.shorter {
  height: 120px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="post">
  <ul id="list">
    <li class="list item">Item 1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This runs the `checkOverflow` function on `load` and when `resize` event is triggered on the Window.

Comment: fantastic – thank you. that's working a treat now.